# hmac returning different hexdigest values to openssl

Tags: python, hmac

For example when I run this command in my terminal:

```
echo -n 'something' | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac  'NhqPtmdS'
```

This is returned:

```
caa686a03a502a0da2985dfea0b0b5798657fc30c2fd917db527d29ea5b23579
```

I'm trying to do this in Python, but I don't know why is returning something different.

This is my code:

```
import base64
from hashlib import sha256
import hmac
key = base64.b64decode('NhqPtmdS')
jsonBytes = bytes('something', "ascii")
hmac_result = hmac.new(key, jsonBytes, sha256).hexdigest()
print(hmac_result)
```

But I'm getting the next result:

```
6a964bd560a9dc763864ddf337d64e5f2ef958e6937ad296084166da0db83eb9
```

Also I tried this:

```
hmac_result = hmac.new(key, jsonBytes, sha256)
base64.b64encode(hmac_result.digest()).decode()
```

But it's not working either.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You should remove `base64.b64decode` to get the same result. `python -c "import hmac, hashlib; print(hmac.new('NhqPtmdS', b'something', hashlib.sha256).hexdigest())"`

Comment: @Artemiy yes I tried that but I'm getting the following error `TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'`

Comment: Ok fixed it, I just put a `b` before `'NhqPtmdS'`